# Nginx-Reverse-Proxy: unauthorized

Tags: node.js, nginx, configuration, nginx-reverse-proxy

I am a beginner in Nginix and I encountered below error. Help me.
First, my conf has not:

```
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/crt.crt; //generated by openssl
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/crt.key; //generated by openssl
```

In this case, when get and install my certificates in nginx, below error was caused.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tRboh.png)

So I have generated ssl certificate using openssl and add ssl certificate like below my conf.

My conf file:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_tokens off;
    resolver 127.0.0.11 ipv6=off;
    server_name GENERIC-SUB-DOMAIN;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name GENERIC-SUB-DOMAIN;
    server_tokens off;
    resolver 127.0.0.11 ipv6=off;
    proxy_pass_header Server;
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/crt.crt; //generated by openssl
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/crt.key; //generated by openssl
    location / {
        set $do_not_cache 1;
        if ($request_uri ~* "\.(css|json|js|text|png|jpg|map|ico|svg|mp3|mp4|txt|jfproj|etx|pfa|fnt|vlw|woff|fot|ttf|sfd|pfb|vfb|otf|gxf|odttf|woff2|pf2|bf|ttc|chr|bdf|fon)") {
           set $do_not_cache 0;
        }
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:9500;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
        proxy_cache seocromom_cache;
        proxy_cache_valid 24h;
        proxy_cache_bypass $do_not_cache;
        proxy_no_cache $do_not_cache;
        proxy_cache_key "$host$uri$is_args$args";
        proxy_cache_lock on;
    }

}
```

Now, I see below error and I can't know why it was caused:

---

Enter PEM pass phrase:

Certbot failed to authenticate some domains (authenticator: nginx). The Certificate Authority reported these problems:
Domain: domain
Type:   unauthorized
Detail: ip: Invalid response from http://domain/.well-known/acme-challenge/60NcdFtxVU3D8au-VAYtqbkg8meWXTqgorOxOqT-n9E: 404

Hint: The Certificate Authority failed to verify the temporary nginx configuration changes made by Certbot. Ensure the listed domains point to this nginx server and that it is accessible from the internet.

Enter PEM pass phrase:
Some challenges have failed.
Ask for help or search for solutions at https://community.letsencrypt.org. See the logfile /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log or re-run Certbot with -v for more details.

---

I think that it may be wrong, but my thinking may be wrong.
I want to know the solution to fix my Nginix conf.

```
ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/crt.crt; //generated by openssl
ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/crt.key; //generated by openssl
```

Comment: You’re redirecting things to another server. That server probably knows nothing about the files certbot writes to check the domain. You’ll need to not redirect those files most likely

Answer (score 0):

the error on the screenshot looks like you add

```
listen ... ssl;
```

but without other ssl directives (*ssl_certificate, ssl_certificate_key, etc*)

---

make simple host config

```
server {
  server_name somedomain.tld;
  listen 80;
  access_log /var/log/nginx/host.access.log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/host.error.log error;
  location ^~ /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
    alias /var/www/html/.well-known/acme-challenge/;
  }
}
```

and start certbot with **--dry-run** key:

```
$ certbot --dry-run certonly --webroot -w /var/www/html --agree-tos -d
```

if output like:

```
Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log
Simulating a certificate request for somedomain.tld
The dry run was successful.
```

try without **--dry-run** key